# name[APPLICATION_COMMAND_INVALID_NAME]: Command name is invalid

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to do a "tip" command (suggest in Italian).
Previously the command was called pool but I decided to rename it, but now it finds me both commands and neither of them work. And when it MAGICALLY works it gives me the error in the title.
I don't even know what code to leave for this problem, you tell me if you need something

Comment: Have you tried re-registering the command

Comment: I resolve this like you said